# Need to call two apis using node,js asynchronously and aggregate the response from both the apis

Tags: node.js

The code I wrote so far is as below.
I don't need the whole response but just part of it.

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

var asyncTasks = [];
var install;

async.series([

    function (callback) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        request('URL', function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body); // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
          }
        });
      }, 5000);
    },

    function (callback) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        request('URL', function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body); // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
          }
        });
      }, 5000);
    }

  ],
  function (error, results) {
    console.log(results);
  });
```

Comment: Could you please format your code so it is legible?

Comment: Thank you for acknowledging my answer. I have reformatted the code in your question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to do the above concurrently would be to use [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async) - of the form of:

```
async.parallel([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
], callback);
```

Another approach is to use a Promises library - [BlueBird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) or [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) are good choices.

Q.All is of the form of:

```
return Q.all([
    promise1,
    promise2
]).spread(function (resultFromPromise1, resultFromPromise2) {
  // do something with the results...
```

});

You could use one of these approaches to parallelise the two calls. The outputs of each will give you an array containing the **results** of each call respectively.

Here is a simple illustration of each approach:

Using **Async.js**

```
var async = require('async');

var task = function (cb, count) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    cb(null, "complete: " + count);
  }, 1000);
};

async.parallel([
  function (cb) {
    task(cb, 'one');
  },
  function (cb) {
    task(cb, 'two');
  }
], function (err, results) {
  console.log(results);
  //[ 'complete: one', 'complete: two' ]
});
```

Using **Q**:

```
var Q = require('q');

function task1(cb, count) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  setTimeout(function () {
    return deferred.resolve(cb(null, count));
  }, 1000);
  return deferred.promise;
}

var myCb = function (err, count) {
  return "complete: " + count;
};

Q.all([task1(myCb, 'one'), task1(myCb, 'two')])
  .then(function (results) {
    console.log(results);
    //[ 'complete: one', 'complete: two' ]
  });
```

Let me know if you are unclear.

Comment: Does this answer provide you with enough information or do you need a concrete example?

Comment: How do i simplify the response ,then i want to aggregate the resoponse form one api to other.

Comment: You are confusing me.. your question states you wish to aggregate the response from both apis.. are you now saying you need to call the apis sequentially because the second api request depends on the output of the first api call? Or do you want to know how to aggregate the results of both calls?

Comment: What do you mean by "aggregate"? In the above examples, each API gets called asynchronously (independently) at the same time, then the results of both api calls is available as an array. Is that what you need?  You could do what you want with the results of the array.

Comment: I just want to aggregate the results of both the calls.

Comment: When i say aggregate it is like joining two tables(if consider the jason results as tables).

Comment: In my examples above, the results are provided as an array. Just take their contents and do whatever aggregation you need. If it is JSON you have to parse that, and join what you need - no idea what that looks like based on your question.  But please phrase your questions clearly, struggling to understand what you are stating. Believe I have answered your question (as stated) and would be grateful if you could mark it as correct as I have spent time ensuring you have clear understanding with working examples of approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are there to help you out in such a case.
I would prefer to use 'Q' library.

I have modified your code to use Q library

```
var Q = require('q');
var request = require('request');


function makeCall() {

Q.all([req1(), req2()])
    .spread(function (res1, res2) {
        // This block is executed once all the functions( Provided in Q.all() ) are finished its execution.
       // Use responses from called functions
    }, function (err) {
       // Error, If any
    });

}

function req1() {

var defer = Q.defer();
var url = ''; // Specify URL
var options = {
    method: 'get', // Method to use
    url: url
}

request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        return defer.reject(err);
    }
    return defer.resolve(body);
});

return defer.promise;
}

function req2() {

var defer = Q.defer();
var url = ''; // Specify URL
var options = {
    method: 'get', // Method to use
    url: url
}
request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        return defer.reject(err);
    }
    return defer.resolve(body);
});
return defer.promise;
}
```

You can find docs for Q library here : [Q docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q)

Comment: SO lets say the jason result i get is
{"id":1,
"Name":hhh
"addres":qqq
}
And i have an array of elements in this format.From my code can i query using id,like when id =1,i need name and address.?

Comment: Could you elaborate your comment, So it would easy to figure out what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: I am trying to use jason query like in the below example to the above code.
var jsonQuery = require('json-query')
var data = {
  people: [
    {name: 'Matt', country: 'NZ'},
    {name: 'Pete', country: 'AU'}
  ]
}
 

jsonQuery('people[country=NZ].name', {
 
 data: data

})
//Sorry for the bad formatting of the code
I am trying to figure out how i can add this to the above code.

Comment: considering the above example i am trying to figure out how i can add it to my code.

Comment: From where you get the 'data' object ? If not misunderstood, You would be getting it in res1/res2 that will either returned form req1() or req2() function